# Undefined method when rendering form partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my questions index page i have a list of all the questions. I want to be able to answer each question right on the page by rendering the answers form. I am getting this error when i try and do that:

```
undefined method `answers' for #<Question:0x00000103dc0100>
```

It highlights the second line of the answers controller:

```
def create
@question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
@answer = @question.answers.new(answer_params)
@answer.save    
end
```

Here is the view:

```
 <% @questions.each do |question| %>
 <%= question.body %>
 <%= render :partial => "answers/form", locals: {question:question} %>
 <% end %>
```

And the form looks like this:

```
 <%= simple_form_for [question, Answer.new] do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :body %>
 <% end %>
```

Lastly, the questions controller:

```
 def index 
 @questions = @comment.questions.order     
 @answer = answer.new 
 end
```

Comment: Seems like you're incorrectly trying to access the `has_one` child relationship. I've posted an answer that should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a `belongs_to` `has_one` relationship, the correct association is this:

```
Question.find(params[:question_id]).answer
```

Note that `answer` is *singular*. This is because each `Question` *has only one* `Answer` - thus, instances of `Question` do not have the method `answers`, as indicated in the exception.

If you wanted each question to have **multiple** answers, you'd define the following associations:

```
# app/models/question.rb
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

# app/models/answer.rb
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

With a `belongs_to` `has_many` relationship, you'd be able to access multiple answers on each question as follows:

```
Question.find(params[:question_id]).answers
```

***UPDATE 1***:

There are a couple ways to add an `Answer` to a `Question`.

**Option 1**: Utilizing the Rails [`build` method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/JoinDependency/build) as made available by the [`has_one` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference):

```
Question.find(params[:question_id]).build_answer(answer_params)
```

**Option 2**: Directly assign an `Answer` to a `Question`:

```
answer = Answer.first
question = Question.first

question.answer = answer
```

In either method, note that, because each `Question` is limited to *a single* `Answer`, a question's existing answer will be *replaced*, rather than added to.

***UPDATE 2***:

Here's how your controller action should look in its entirety utilizing each of the suggested methods:

**Option 1**:

```
# app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
def create
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  @question.build_answer(answer_params)
end
```

**Option 2**:

```
# app/controllers/answers_controller.rb
def create
  @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
  @question.answer = @answer
end
```

Comment: Ok so i changed @answer = @question.answers.new(answer_params) to answer.new but am now getting undefined method new? (Also tried adding  .answer at the end of the line above)

Comment: I'm having trouble with option one. It still gives me the same error for the @question.answer.new(answer_params) line. Also, is @answer = Answer.new necessary in the questions controller?

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message it's returning? `@answer = Answer.new` isn't specifically necessary. The only requirement is that the object passed to the association is an instance of `Answer` – it doesn't matter if it's new or existing.

Comment: The error now: undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

Comment: There is no reason to be invoking the `new` method. Use `build_answer` __instead__ – not __in addition to__.

Comment: No error this time it doesn't seem to have saved. To check if its saved what should i use instead of 'if @answer.save? '

Comment: Yes, you should. I've also updated my answer with proposed code for your controller actions. If this answer has helped resolve your question, please consider upvoting/accepting it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you have belongs_to question, and has_one :answer, then you can only do the following:

```
Question.find(1).answer
```

not

```
Question.find(1).answers
```

which would be a has_many relationship

## EDIT

```
@answer = answer.new
```

is almost definitely not what you want.

You want

```
@answer = Answer.new
```

Or

```
@answer = @question.answers.new
```

Or

```
@answer = @question.answer.new
```

Comment: Tried changing answers to just answer in the controller and now giving me a undefined method new error.

Comment: check your relationships and get it right. has_one or has_many

Comment: @answer = @question.answer.new is giving me undefined method `answer' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: @SherwynGoh, this answer does not address the OP's `has_one` relationship. You've only depicted a way to add a child to a `has_many` relationship. Also, as already mentioned, `@question.answer.new` produces an exception.

Comment: thats because @ question is nil. check @ comment.questions and @ comment

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not set your associations in your model. Basically, Rails is looking for a method called "answers" in your Question model. Have you set `belongs_to :question` in your Answer model and `has_many :answers` in your Question model? Can't tell if that's the real issue without seeing your model code.

More info on associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Edit - since you have a has_one association, the syntax is a bit different.

Try changing "answers" to "answer" - see the table on generated methods for different association types in this doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001834

Comment: I have belongs_to :question in the answers model and has_one :answer in the questions.